# Excel Formulas Equal 0 and Calculating 8 Threads

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been having issues getting sumif, sumifs, countif, countifs formulas to calculate correctly on excel. When using any of these formulas, the sum = 0 and the document will start calculating 8 threads. Unfortunately, the calculation never completes and requires me to force close to application and lose the progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To help you we will need more details.

Comment: the `***IF(s)` formula are calc heavy, placing too many on the sheet referring to a large dataset will cause this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is a pretty small document, so the dataset should not be too large to create the issue. I have done the same functions for years that this is the first time that I have encountered the issue. Is there a way that I can attach the document to the thread so you could take a look?